# How to open excel file with in a folder with different file types using Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a script that opens and extracts data from .xlsm excel files in a folder that contains xls, xlsm and PDF files. I'm having trouble opening .xlsm files only. I can filter out .xlsm with an if statement but I'm lost on how to open the first .xlsm file encountered in the directory using  xlrd.open_workbook() . I'm not sure what should be placed inside the parenthesis for xlrd.open_workbook() since you'd normally put an exact file path in there.   This is what I've got so far, any help is much appreciated.

```
import os
import xlrd

directory = r"C:\Users\folder"
os.chdir(directory)

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
   for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.xlsm'):
            workbook = xlrd.open_workbook()
            sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
            #extract data
```

Comment: Try `os.path.join(dirname, name)`.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked!